# Any way to grab a logo icon from website URL, programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, webview

I am in the process of creating an activity where I will show the list of website visited with its logo and its alias name chosen by user.

e.g.

- *Recent Websites Visited*

  logo1 website1/alias name

  logo2 website2/alias name

  .

  . so no

The question is, (Ref. attached image) How to get website logo displayed on left side of http://?

[image: Like below I want to just grab the icon and save it locally]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's called a favicon, and all you have to do is:

1. If there's an icon at `/favicon.ico`, use that.
2. Otherwise, get the content of the page, and extract the location from `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="URL goes here" />`. You’ll need to use an HTML parser and find the `<link>` with a `rel` of either `icon` or `shortcut icon`.

Comment: Thanks much for your advise, I will implement and let you know my findings. -Best

Comment: I got it working with the help of google url provided for this approach. http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.domain.com
to grab the favIcon. Still struggling with background to make transparent as some of them are with white BKG and other one with black. Not sure how to handle those background dynamically. @minitTech Thanks for your help it got me started.

Comment: @mask Your code it is working but the icon it is smaller do you know how ti make bigger and do not crash the favicon size.

Answer (score 22):

Use this website:

`https://besticon-demo.herokuapp.com/allicons.json?url=www.stackoverflow.com`

It will find all logos for a website in multiple sizes and return a nice json string with meta data including the url to the icon.  You simply replace `www.stackoverflow.com` with your domain.

The site also has a gui for entering in websites manually if you prefer:

```
https://besticon-demo.herokuapp.com/
```

Here is a sample string returned from querying for the stack overflow website:

```
{
   "url":"www.stackoverflow.com",
   "icons":[
      {
         "url":"http://stackoverflow.com/apple-touch-icon.png",
         "width":158,
         "height":158,
         "format":"png",
         "bytes":3445,
         "error":null,
         "sha1sum":"c78bd457575a3221c6b3d0d17ffb00ffc63d7cd0"
      },
      {
         "url":"http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d",
         "width":32,
         "height":32,
         "format":"ico",
         "bytes":5430,
         "error":null,
         "sha1sum":"4f32ecc8f43d0986b9c6ce9f37999e86c0b829ef"
      },
      {
         "url":"http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico",
         "width":32,
         "height":32,
         "format":"ico",
         "bytes":5430,
         "error":null,
         "sha1sum":"4f32ecc8f43d0986b9c6ce9f37999e86c0b829ef"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: @JackFairfield How it is possible to get this icon and to show in `ImageView` with `Glide`

Comment: Site appears down as of August 2020.

Answer (score 22):

I know I am late but this API will help others

Android doesn't support favicon files natively, you can fetch favicon in different ways but can't show/use it.

Google provides free API to get favicon in image format.

https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain_url=microsoft.com

Use Picasso to show fetched favicon in an image view.

Comment: this will only return a value if the icon has a 64px image set, it could easily have a 16 or 32 instead one wouldn't know.

Comment: This is what I exactly want.

Answer (score 8):

Use this [logo.clearbit.com/stackoverflow.com](http://logo.clearbit.com/stackoverflow.com)

You can even customize to get particular size and grascaled version

[logo.clearbit.com/stackoverflow.com?size=80&greyscale=true](http://logo.clearbit.com/stackoverflow.com?size=80&greyscale=true)

Comment: Just checked. Clearbit doesn't provide this feature in this way anymore.

Comment: Looks like it is back - https://clearbit.com/logo

Answer (score 3):

**This method can be used to get Favicon Icon bitmap**

```
 private Bitmap fetchFavicon(Uri uri) {
        final Uri iconUri = uri.buildUpon().path("favicon.ico").build();
        Log.i(TAG, "Fetching favicon from: " + iconUri);

        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try
        {
            URLConnection conn = new URL(iconUri.toString()).openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8192);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to fetch favicon from " + iconUri, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the new `API` the `conn.connect` will crash the application.
Do you have any new suggest ?

Comment: while doing network operation always use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
imageview1.setImageBitmap(webview1.getFavicon());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python library which tries to infer the logo image from a URL:

https://github.com/dcollien/urlimage

it parses the HTML at the url, and tries a whole bunch of things including:

- meta tag with itemprop="image" or property="image"
- meta tag with
  property="og:image:secure_url" or property="og:image"
- meta tag with
  name="twitter:image"
- meta tag for Microsoft tiles, with: name="msapplication-wide310x150logo", name="msapplication-square310x310logo", name="msapplication-square150x150logo", name="msapplication-square70x70logo"
- link tag with rel="apple-touch-icon"
- link tag with rel="icon"
- tries out "{scheme}://{domain}/favicon.ico" to see if it exists
- otherwise pulls out the first img tag (next to an h1)

Answer (score 0):

[Clearbit have an API](https://clearbit.com/logo) that can help with this. It's currently free if you attribute the link.

The docs for it are hard to find but [here is an FAQ](https://help.clearbit.com/hc/en-us/articles/6987867587607-Logo-API-I-FAQ) answer with details.

In short, you make a get request as below where `:domain` is the domain of the site you want the logo from:

```
https://logo.clearbit.com/:domain
```