# How to load high quality favicon in android?

Tags: android

I want to get sites icon and set it into imageView. I see this solution in another topic but this way, return a low-resolution icon:

```
Picasso.get().load("https://www.yahoo.com/favicon.ico")
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

In fact, I added "/favicon.ico" to the base URL of the site.

Do you have another way to get a high-quality favicon?

Comment: `favicon` are low-resolution images, you can not make them high-quality. low-res is a property of `favicon`

Comment: oh, sorry. How to get Site Logo? @RahulGaur

Comment: please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37996543/7948109), this answer showed a way to get different logo with size from any site

Comment: this site open with an Application error. @RahulGaur